# Using cv::Mat1f as cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11

I have this method:

```
static void WriteMatVect(const std::string& filename, const std::vector<cv::Mat>& mats);
```

...

```
void FileSystem::WriteMatVect(const std::string& filename, const std::vector<cv::Mat>& mats){
    size_t size = mats.size();
    FileSystem::saveArray(&size,1,filename);
    if(mats.empty()){
        std::cerr<<"error WriteMatVect: no cv::Mat in mats"<<std::endl;
        return;
    }
    for(size_t i=0 ; i<mats.size() ; i++)
        FileSystem::WriteMat(filename, mats[i], true);
}
```

Which is called passing a `std::vector<cv::Mat1f>` as `mats`. But this returns the following error:

```
../FileSystem.hpp:28:14: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘std::vector<cv::Mat_<float> >’ to ‘const std::vector<cv::Mat>&’
```

A simple workaround could be changing `WriteMatVect` signature using `std::vector<cv::Mat1f>& mats`, but this would make `WriteMatVect` too strict (it would work only with float matrices), while I would like to do it as general as generic as possible. The only solution that comes to my mind is using templates, so `const std::vector<T> &mats`. Any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

A `Mat1f` is convertible to a `Mat`, but a `vector<Mat1f>` is not convertible to a `vector<Mat>`.

A simple workaround is to copy your `vector<Mat1f>` to the correct `vector<Mat>`. Remember that data are not copied, so it shouldn't be that slow.

```
vector<Mat1f> v;
...
vector<Mat> u;
u.reserve(v.size());
for(const auto& m : v) { u.push_back(m); }

WriteMatVect(u);
```

Answer (score 0):

**The problem:**
I think you are mixing derived with base class:

(see the compiler error)

> > no known conversion for argument 2 from `std::vector<cv::Mat_<float> >` 
> > to `const std::vector<cv::Mat>&`

```
template<typename _Tp> class Mat_ : public Mat
{
public:
    // ... some specific methods
    //         and
    // no new extra fields
};
```

**Solution 1:**
The template class `Mat_` is derived from `Mat`, so maybe you can change your code from `vector<cv::Mat>` to `vector<cv::Mat*>`and the argument from `std::vector<cv::Mat1f>` to `std::vector<cv::Mat*>`, the downcasting will be implicit when you push the matrix to the vectors.

Then your method will be:

```
static void WriteMatVect(const std::string& filename, const std::vector<cv::Mat*>& mats);
```

**[EDITED] Solution 2:**
Another possible workaround *(if you prefer not to change the calling method)* is to slice the objects in the `std::vector<cv::Mat1f> mats`, so use a `std::vector<cv::Mat> mats` instead, for example when you push the objects:

```
cv::Mat1f matFelement;
std::vector<cv::Mat> mats
mats.push_back(matFelement); //object sliced form Mat1f to Mat
```

Comment: I would prefer not to change the calling method. Would the template solution would work?

Comment: I think that if you use the "template solution" implies to change the signature of your method too...